# Multiple url links in a text area field and saving them into a database

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to save the links that are entered in the text area field. The links are seperated by a new line/enter. So in the example I made here below, he should add 3 lines in the table for each url link. But for some reason he isn't doing that.

**TEXT AREA**

www.url1.com

www.url2.com

www.url3.com

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="url" name="url"></textarea>
```

**PHP**

```
$url = isset($_POST['url']);
$links_array = explode('\n', $url);

foreach($links_array as $url)
{
    $query3 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO links(sigaren_id, link) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM sigaren ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1), '$url')");
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards

Comment: Characters like `'\n'` will only get evaluated if in double quotes.  Change it to `"\n"`

Comment: Changed it but still not correct in my database. Only getting '1' as saved text in the url column of my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using single quotes, use double quotes around the \n string

```
if(isset($_POST['url'])){
    $links_array = explode("\n", $_POST['url']);

    foreach($links_array as $url)
    {
        $query3 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO links(sigaren_id, link) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM sigaren ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1), '$url')");
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Also, you're setting $url to isset($_POST['url']) which returns a true and false value, NOT the actual content of the variable being assessed, I've changed my answer to reflect this.

Here's a great answer describing the different in how PHP processes 'content' strings and "content" strings https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/3944304

Comment: Changed it but still not correct in my database. Only getting '1' as saved text in the url column of my table.

Comment: Sorry, edited my answer, you had an additional problem with the isset() line

Comment: Did it! awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotes to define newlines as characters:

```
"\n"
```

Single quotes notate strings, double quotes notate characters

```
$post_keys = explode("\n", $_POST['url']);
```